# IDA Script, get function that has random characters in its name

Tags: ida, idapython, script

I was trying to figure out if there is a way I can get the address for a function name that has random characters in it.
For example the function name is *"Player_GetStats_m29275"* here the *"m292755"*
is random characters. So I want to search the name of the function by just *"Player_GetStats"* so it gives me the address of the function.

**get_name_ea** is not good for doing this. I can search the function with **find_text** but it's too slow and takes a lot of time even if I mention the segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, IDA doesn't have a `function_name_to_address()` that gets a pattern and returns an address. You can iterate over all the functions and check if their name matches the one you want. It should not take too long.

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
from idc import *

ea = BeginEA()
for funcAddr in Functions(SegStart(ea), SegEnd(ea)):
    funcName = GetFunctionName(funcAddr)
    # Check if the function name starts with "Player_GetStats"
    if funcName.startswith("Player_GetStats"):
        print "Function %s is at 0x%x" % (funcName, funcAddr)
```

Alternatively you can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to match the name you want:

```
import re

funcName = "Player_GetStats_m29275"
re.compile("^Player_GetStats_\w\d{5}$")
if pattern.match(funcName):
   "%s match the pattern" % funcName
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` is for "begins with"
- `\w` matches one word character ("m" in this case)
- `\d` matches a digit
- `{5}` checks that the previous expression (`\d`) is repeating 5 times
- `$` is for "end of line"

Comment: `idc.get_func_name` in modern IDAPython ... see https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml